# TFS2010 gated check-in "failed to apply label" when adding new files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, tfvc, gated-checkin

We're getting a 'Failed to apply label' in a Gated Check-in scenario, on an MVC3 project, when adding new files.

After some Googling, it seems that it's because we're using a MSBuild script to do extra stuff: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/af9c65a2-dc27-40df-ae6d-958008ad106f

We need that 'extra stuff' because when doing a release build of the solution TFS seems to be placing the binaries in completely the wrong folder as we are using an MVC AREA. So the TFSBuild.proj is calling another MSBuild file to do the file copying. We dont have the expertise to figure out the TFS2010 way of doing things - ie Windows Workflow.

So the question is - how can we continue to use Gated Check-in but fix this applying a lable issue?

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

You have a generic issue with Gated Check-in: check-in simply happens after any chance you have to enforce labeling. I was also faced with this matter, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280730/tfs-2010-issue-with-tracking-changesets-in-builds-that-are-a-result-of-gated-che) older post.
My resolution was to simply remove the labeling in all my Gated Check-in builds & assign this task to the *nighlty* builds.